# SSRS report group parameter expression causing divide error

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a report that uses an expression to sort a group but when choosing one value from the parameter it returns an "The sort expression for the grouping 'grp' contains an error: Attempted to divide by zero."

The expression being used is below;

```
=Choose(Parameters!sort.Value,
Choose(Parameters!set.Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value,Fields!    ManagementArea.Value,Fields!RentGroup.Value,Fields!Tenure.Value),
-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp"),
Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp"),
-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp"))
```

Any thoughts amendments appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to your report code to handle divide by zero error:

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

Then in your expression call the function:

```
code.Divider( Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp") )
```

Comment: Thanks SuperSimmer, where/how would I add this function? Never created  function before in SSRS.

Comment: In visual studio right mouse click outside the report area, report properties, code.Enter the function code inside the custom code box.

Comment: I noticed I missed something when copying the function. the error now is [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'Divisor' of 'Public Function Divider (Divider as Double, Divisor as Double) As Object' I put the code divider in the sort of the group. Any ideas on this error?

Answer (score 0):

How about you simple check if your `Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")` returns 0 or null, if it does you do not need to divide `Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")`
else just divide.

I have updated expression below.

```
=Choose(Parameters!sort.Value,
Choose(Parameters!set.Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value,Fields!    ManagementArea.Value,Fields!RentGroup.Value,Fields!Tenure.Value),
-Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp"),
Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp"),
-IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")) or Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")=0,Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp"),  Sum(Fields!RentCollected.Value,"grp")/Sum(Fields!RentDue.Value,"grp")))
```

Comment: It comes back with the same error. Any further ideas?

Comment: Could it be the expression in the grouping? =choose(Parameters!set.Value,Fields!IncomeOfficer.Value,Fields!ManagementArea.Value,Fields!RentGroup.Value,Fields!Tenure.Value)